# Emulation and Energy Consumption in QEMU

Tags: performance, qemu, energy

I need to emulate a particular architecture namely Cortex ARM A9.
I was thinking about QEMU (what do you think about it) with a distro linux.

The problem is that I would to measure the energy consumption of a mathematical operation on this architecture, for example an exponentiation, or an elliptic curve addition/multiplication. The programming language could be python or C.

Do you have an idea on what I can to do that?

Furthermore, in an emulated architecture who guarantee me that I will have the right timings about the execution of these operations?

Comment: I don't know a lot about such low-level hardware emulation, but IFAIK, QEMU is not designed to emulate the physical part of the hardware itself (eg. energy consumption). Thus, it does not seems to be the tool you need. You probably need a lower-level tool (which will probably be insanely slow). However, regarding the research paper "Micro-architectural Simulation of In-order and Out-of-order ARM Microprocessors with gem5", such tool seems hard to find. If you want accurate energy consumption results, I think it is better and easier to just buy a chip, test it and measure this yourself!

Comment: @JérômeRichard but if I want to estimate the time required to do an operations, do you think that QEMU is enough or not?

Comment: Sadly, I do not think it is enough too. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925699/how-to-benchmark-in-qemu-i386-system-using-rdtsc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QEMU is neither cycle accurate or a microarchictecture simulation. You may be able to build your own energy model with the recently added plugins but I suspect you need more low level tools.